# Place names in movie titles - stumped on this puzzle

Tags: cipher, word

I'm working on this puzzle where the solution is either a word or phrase with no theme.

The first part of the puzzle had incorrect movie titles with cities, states, etc, and the solution to the first part of the puzzle is the actual places in the movie titles.

Below is the list of all the actual places.

Somehow, this list should yield a word, but I have no idea what to do to get this word.  They are arranged in chronological order.

**Sorted by release date:**

> St. Louis
>   Tangier
>   Nuremberg
>   Flint
>   Atlantic City
>   London
>   East LA
>   Tombstone
>   Providence
>   Arlington
>   Reno
>   Union
>   Elizabethtown
>   Annapolis
>   Talladega
>   New Orleans
>   Rome

**Sorted alphabetically:**

> Annapolis
>   Arlington
>   Atlantic City
>   East LA
>   Elizabethtown
>   Flint
>   London
>   New Orleans
>   Nuremberg
>   Providence
>   Reno
>   Rome
>   St. Louis
>   Annapolis
>   Talladega
>   Tangier
>   Tombstone
>   Union

*** Full Puzzle ***

> Meet Me in 'Maryland'      1944 - Judy Garland, Margaret O'Brien
>
> 'California' Incident      1953 - George Brent, Mari Aldon
>
> Judgment at 'Rhode Island'     1961 - Maximilian Schell, Spencer Tracy
>
> In Like 'Morocco'      1967 - James Coburn, Lee J. Cobb
>
> 'Michigan'     1980 - Susan Sarandon, Burt Lancaster
>
> American Werewolf in 'Virginia'        1981 - David Naughton, Jenny Agutter
>
> Born in 'Italy'        1987 - Cheech Marin, Daniel Stern
>
> 'New Jersey'       1993 - Kurt Russell, Bill Paxton
>
> Outside 'United Kingdom'       1999 - Alec Baldwin, Shawn Hatosy
>
> 'Louisiana' Road       1999 - Jeff Bridges, Tim Robbins
>
> Waking up in 'Germany'     2002 - Patrick Swayze, Billy Bob Thornton
>
> xXx: State of the 'Nevada'     2005 - Ice Cube, Willem Dafoe
>
> 'Arizona'      2005 - Orlando Bloom, Kirsten Dunst
>
> 'Alabama'      2006 - Tyrese Gibson, James Franco
>
> 'New York' Nights: The Ballad of Ricky Bobby       2006 - Will Ferrell, John C. Reilly
>
> Bad Lieutenant: Port of Call 'Kentucky'        2009 - Nicolas Cage, Eva Mendes
>
> When in 'Missouri'     2010 - Kristen Bell, Josh Duhamel

***My Doubt***

I tried a whole bunch of different counting patterns and also introduced some ciphers into the mix, but I still can't figure it out.  Can anyone help me out in getting to the probable solution ?

Comment: Taking the first letter of each place-name and rearranging the letters gives A TRANSPARENT FLUTE. Could this be the answer or do you need exactly one word?

Comment: Another idea: is it definitely wordplay or could it be something like drawing lines on a map joining each place to the next so as to form letters which could be arranged into words?

Comment: Could you make a few > blocks of different organizations? (Like alphabetical, and by length)

Comment: Is this related to your roman Gods question? Could it have a similar answer? Sort by increasing word-length and then take ever 1st, 2nd, 3rd letter of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd... word? if there is no theme or additional clue, I think it is simply a too broad question. I VTC for that reason.

Comment: @BmyGuest Grumpyguts.

Comment: Could the answer be based on the full movie titles rather than just the places?

Comment: Why not post the full puzzle?

Comment: I think that the answer is just one word.  I'm trying different anagrams of the first letters, but I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is:

> Uranus.

The solution:

> Each clue mentions a state or country that has a city belonging in the title of another movie on the list. 
> The first clue mentions 'Maryland', Annapolis is a city in Maryland, and 'Annapolis' belongs in the title of the 14th movie.  
> Continuing, the 14th clue mentions 'Alabama', Talladega is a city in Alabama, and 'Talladega' belongs in the title of the 15th movie.
>  The 15th clue mentions 'New York', Union is a city in New York, and 'Union' belongs in the title of the 12th movie.
> Continuing in this fashion, we get a cyclic ordering of the list of cities the OP found:

- Annapolis
- Talladega
- Union
- Reno
- Nuremberg
- Providence
- London
- Arlington
- New Orleans
- Elizabethtown
- Tombstone
- Atlantic City
- Flint
- Tangier
- East LA
- Rome
- St Louis

> Reading the first letter of each city name gives **ATURNPLANETAFTERS**. Cyclicly permuting the letters and adding spaces gives **PLANET AFTER SATURN**. 'Uranus' is the planet after Saturn.

Comment: I can't figure out how to deal with spoilers and a list. If someone wants to mess with this, feel free.